# List all installed monospace fonts

Tags: 20.04, fonts

How can I list all monospaced fonts which are installed on my Ubuntu 20.04?

I can use `fc-list` to list all installed fonts, but that doesn't seem to show me which ones are monospaced.

Comment: You should be able to pass a match pattern to `fc-list` ex. `fc-list :mono`. See for example [Command to list all monospace fonts known to fontconfig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363365/command-to-list-all-monospace-fonts-known-to-fontconfig)

Comment: @steeldriver That seems to work.  You could post that as an answer.